# react-native cli tool syntax error on windows 10

Tags: windows, react-native

When trying to run 'react-native' from a windows 10 machine it returns a syntax error:

```
C:\Users\josetapadas\githubissue\node_modules\react-native\packager\react-packager\src\node-haste\index.js:40
  constructor({
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\José Alves\src\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\José Alves\src\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\server\util/attachHMRServer.js:11:34)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
```

I've basically downloaded react-native-cli and was trying to bootstrap a new project.

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
react-native
```

These are the following versions I have installed right now on my Windows 10 machine:

- react-native-cli: 1.0.0
- react-native: 0.33.0
- node: v4.4.6

Does this error affected anyone and anyone has a clue on how to solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed with react-native 0.41 and above.